# Making an API call while running protractor tests

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I have built a web application using `angular2.0` and `typescript`. Now I am writing `E2E` for my site using `protractor`.

Now, in one of my tests I need to make an API call(HTTP GET request) and use the response value as an input in my test case.

So basically I want to know how to make a `GET request` in `Protractor-Jasmine` and use the result/response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Protractor runs on top of nodejs, and under the hood is calling Selenium API. You can use all of the node libraries, including `request`.

Choose between import/require:

```
import * as request from 'request'; 
var request = require('request');
```

And perform your `GET` request:

```
it('Should reach google.com', done => {
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
        done(); //informs runner that the asynchronous code has finished
    });
});
```

Check out this links:

- https://nodejs.org/api/http.html
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: So I tried this,

`it('should return 200 and contain proper body', function() {
    request('http://www.google.com', function(error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
      console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
      expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(500);
    });
  });`

But the test seems to pass with no errors

Comment: request work asynchronously. Let me update my answer :) Updated. Place your assertion before `done()`. Now it should work as you expect

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks for the quick reply