# How to Properly Test Observables for e2e testing in Karma?

Tags: jasmine, observable, e2e-testing, angular7, angular-e2e

Currently I am trying to write a test that will perform the following actions:

- Load my Component
- Wait for return from a service class (HTTP Call + Observable)
- Check value returned.

Service class:

```
getMyInfo(): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.httpClient.get(`${this.serviceurl}/all`) as Observable<any[]>;
}
```

Relevant component code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getMyInfo().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      console.log('I was called')
      this.myInfo = data;
    })
}
```

In test class, using this method from Service will not work, the method is called, however the return is never applied in the class (Subscription).

Using a stub works, but this is not what I want, since I want to e2e.

```
const serviceStub = {
  getMyInfo() {
    return fakeAsyncResponse([{  id: 1,name: 'myname'}]);
  }
};

 it("should request names on component initiation.", inject([FrontendComponent, Service], async(component: FrontendComponent, service: Service) => {
    let debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    let Service = debugElement.injector.get(Service);
    let incrementSpy = spyOn(Service, 'getMyInfo').and.callThrough();
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(incrementSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    fixture.detectChanges();    
    console.log(component.myInfo);
    expect(component.myInfo.length).toEqual(1);
  }));
```

To sum up, how can I handle real http calls and then process the expect assertion without stubbing the service classes?

Comment: Please provide some code examples, your question is too vague.

Comment: FifthEon added the code I currently have, however it does not interact with service over http like I wanted since it is a stub.

Comment: Do you want to trigger actual service call for e2e? We usually run a dev express server  and respond to http request with locally stored JSON data from files.

Comment: Actual service, I dont want to mock it at all..

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182309/making-an-api-call-while-running-protractor-tests

Comment: @nircraft, that means I cannot use the service? is that true? I will need to rewrite my service classes to use protractor?